# How to use pointers in a circular doubly linked-list

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I can't get the compiler to stop looping in the while loop. For this function, there are two chains and you are suppose to weave them together. For example, Chain 1 has a head sentinel node and then 1,2,3,4. Chain 2 has a head sentinel and then 5,6,7,8. Output should be Chain1 - head,1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8 and Chain 2 only has head. An empty chain would still have a head node. If one chain is shorter than the other, the remaining nodes should just append itself to Chain1 because output is always Chain1.

I've been adjusting where things point to and it previously was repeatedly printing out problem 2, now it is repeatedly printing out problem4. I think I'm  not pointing out where my pointers should go, but I'm not even sure what they're pointing to right now.

```
 void Chain::weave(Chain & other) {     
    if(other.height_ != this->height_ || other.width_ != width_){
        cout << "Block sizes differ." << endl;
    } else if (other.size() == 0){
        return;
    }else if (this->size() == 0 && other.size() >= 1){
        this->head_->next = other.head_->next;
        other.head_->next->prev = this->head_;
        this->head_->prev = other.head_->prev;
        other.head_->prev->next = this->head_;
    } else {
        Node * current = head_->next;
        Node * othernode = other.head_->next;
        Node * pre;
        Node * nex;
        Node * opre;
        Node * onex;
        while (current != nullptr || othernode !=nullptr){
            if (current != nullptr && othernode !=nullptr){
                current = current->next;
                othernode = othernode->next;
                opre = othernode->prev;
                onex = other.head_->next->next;
                pre = current->prev;
                nex = current->next;

                current->next = othernode;
                othernode->prev = current;
                nex->prev = othernode;
                othernode->next = nex;
                current = nex;
                othernode = onex;

                cout << this->size() << endl;
                cout << other.size() << endl;
                cout << "problem1" << endl;

                if(onex == other.head_){
                    othernode = nullptr;
                    cout << "problem2" << endl;
                }
                if (current == this->head_){
                    current = nullptr;
                    cout << "problem3" << endl;
                }
            }else if(current == nullptr && othernode != nullptr){

                this->head_->next = othernode;

                cout << "problem4" << endl;

            }             
        }
       }

    }
```

Comment: This is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

This line, just before you print "problem 4":

```
                this->head_->next = othernode;
```

should be

```
                pre->next->next = othernode;
                break;
```

You don't want to change, `head_` unless the list is empty.  But you previously checked for that.  So you know the list is not empty at this point in the code.

The node that you want to change is the one before `current`, which is `pre->next` at that point.  The `pre->next->next` is `current`, which is a `nullptr`.  You want to set that to `othernode`.

You also need to add another `else`:

```
                } else {
                    break;
```

This handles the case where `current` is not null but `othernode` is.  In that case, you're done.  But your code would keep looping.

---

A better solution might be to change the `while` to

```
while (current != this->head_ && othernode != other.head_) {
```

and get rid of the internal `if`.  You can then check

```
if (othernode != other.head_) {
```

after the `while` loop.  Then just do

```
    pre->next->next = othernode;
```

That would get rid of the `break`.

This also gets rid of the `nullptr` checks and assignment.

---

The following code is also problematic.

```
            current = current->next;
            othernode = othernode->next;
            opre = othernode->prev;
            onex = other.head_->next->next;
            pre = current->prev;
            nex = current->next;

            current->next = othernode;
            othernode->prev = current;
            nex->prev = othernode;
            othernode->next = nex;
            current = nex;
            othernode = onex;
```

You don't want `current = current->next`, as that advances the pointer and you already have it advanced as either `head_->next` or `nex`.  So just get rid of that line and `othernode = othernode->next`.

```
            onex = other.head_->next->next;
```

As previously, this should not reference the `head_`.  That makes it the same value on every iteration.  Just

```
            onex = othernode->next;
```

I think that this is everything, but I haven't tried to run it.  There may be more errors that I didn't notice.